# Windows not recognizing CDs, but Blu-Ray drive will still play them

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, media-player, compact-disc

I have a LG Blu-Ray writer, a WH10LS30.  My OS is Windows 7, 64-bit.  After the last three updates received from Windows Update (though I don't know them to be the cause), my CDs are not being recognized as such in Windows.

The CDs are viewable in Windows Explorer, and I can click on the .cda files, and Windows Media Player will come up, but it won't play anything.  The size of the files is shown as zero.

If I open up a different program, like Blaze Media Pro, then I can play the files just fine.

So the Blu-Ray drive is working fine, but there is still a problem.  This is pretty hard to look up on the Internet, since most people posting have drive problems.

I've run the System File Checker and it did what repairs it felt it needed to do, but to no avail.  Troubleshooter didn't help at all.

Screenshot #1, Drive in Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer Drives]

Screenshot #2, CD in Windows Explorer:

[image: Windows Explorer CD]

Screenshot #3, WMP 12 Library Tab

[image: WMP12 Library Tab]

Any Ideas?

Comment: Can you use cmd to access the drive? Does it show a non-zero file size of any of the contents?

Comment: @soandos, it will access it, and list the contents, but the size of each file is showing as exactly 44 bytes.

Comment: Can you mount a virtual CD and see if the same thing happens?

Comment: @soandos, I have a virtual CD mounted all the time (from my usb backup drive) and the one file on it looks normal spacewise (it's an exe).

Comment: If the CD itself is good, then I have no idea, sorry

Comment: @soandos, yeh, it's a tough one, I've spent hours cruising the net looking for answers and trying stuff.

Comment: Just thinking aloud: its a bug that impacts cmd, explorer, and media player (all of which probably share a way of getting file/directory data) but not arbitrary programs or virtual drives...
Does the problem occur with other physical external volumes?

Comment: @soandos, USBs and External USB HDs work fine.  I just stuck a DVD in the player and noticed that the autoplay didn't work, but the filesizes were right, and Cyberlink played it when I clicked on an individual file.  I notice that Windows Explorer still calls it a CD Drive with a DVD in it, but maybe that's normal and I just never noticed before.

Comment: grasping at straws: user profile dependent? system restore?

Comment: @soandos, I disabled system restore because I have SSDs that I don't want to overwork.  Only one account on this computer, so I don't think it's a profile issue.

Comment: I meant that if you create another account, will it work for that account. Btw, is really keeping two copies of the registry (or even a thousand for that matter) such a big deal?

Comment: @soandos, it's the updating that wears on the SSD, they have a high failure rate, see Jeff's article [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2011/05/the-hot-crazy-solid-state-drive-scale.html).

Comment: It does not seem like a large amount of data. In addition, see [here][1] and [this][2] Intel seems to have decent failure rates. In addition I would assume that failure rates have gone some since then (though not much).

  [1]:http://forums.storagereview.com/index.php/topic/29329-ssd-failure-rates-compared-to-hard-drives/
  [2]:http://www.pcworld.com/businesscenter/article/213442/solid_state_drives_no_better_than_others_survey_says.html

Comment: @soandos, pics added.

Answer (score 0):

Your drive is working fine.

Audio-CDs will show up with tracks as files, but they contain no audio data. Audio-CDs need to be accessed as audio. In my Media Player the audio cd is listed automagically in the library tab.

Comment: I've added pics to show that it isn't shown in the Library tab.  Also note that it was working fine just last week, and only recently has started doing this (not necessarily all of the behavior, but it had no problem playing audio CDs in WMP before).